# IOS weird build folder name?

Tags: ios, build

When setting my build path under XCode's "Preferences", I choose a folder on my machine called "IOSBuilds".

When I build a project to this folder, it tacks on a string of characters to the build name and creates a folder such as...

"PDFDemo-bwxfbukmtuozzpbehzgnkzkquebc"

How can I prevent these extra characters?

I end up with several of these folders.  Can I not simply build to the same folder (i.e. "PDFDemo") each time?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by going to Xcode -> Preferences and, under the Locations tab, setting Build Location to "Place build products in locations specified by targets."

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything to help the "-bwxfbukmtuozzpbehzgnkzkquebc" issue.  Unless I'm doing something wrong in the setting things up in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, try setting a build location in the build settings of the target itself (not the project.) In the Build Settings of the target, change Build Products Path.

Comment: Ah, and the Per-configuration Build Products Path.